Pstricks axes label size change: why?
I "draw" two pstricks pictures, one after the other. At the beginning of each of them, I specify the font size (\small in my example). Then I draw axes, with labelFontSize=\normalsize, which should result in the same \small size as the whole picture. I know that this is useless, but I just add it in the code in case I want to change it in the future. However, the font size of the labels are smaller in the first picture than in the second one. Does anyone know why?
I compile with TeXstudio, using XeLaTeX and the chain DVI->PS->PDF (but it does the same with LuaLaTeX, and I doubt that the vizualisation chain would change anything).
Here My code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-func}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%% Fig 1Fp112 - 2023-24 - BEGIN %%%%%%%    
\psset{%
    xunit=1.2cm,%
    yunit=.2cm,%
    algebraic=true,%
    dotstyle=*,%
    dotsize=5pt 0,%
    linewidth=.8pt,% default: 0.8pt
    arrowsize=3pt 2,%
    arrowinset=0.25%
    }
\def\xmin{-2.8}
\def\xmax{3.6}
\def\ymin{-8}
\def\ymax{19.7}
\begin{pspicture*}(\xmin,\ymin)(\xmax,\ymax)
    \small
    \psaxes[%
        linewidth=.8pt,%
        labelFontSize=\normalsize,%
        labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,%
        xAxis=true,%
        yAxis=true,%
        showorigin=false,%
        Dx=1,%
        Dy=5,%
        ticksize=-3pt,%
        xsubticks=2,%
        ysubticks=5%
        ]{->}(0,0)(\xmin,\ymin)(\xmax,\ymax)
    \uput{.2cm}[120](\xmax,0){$x$}
    \uput{.2cm}[-30](0,\ymax){$y$}
    \psgrid[%
        gridcolor=black,% default: grey
        griddots=5,%
        gridlabels=0pt,%
        subgriddiv=0,%
        subgriddots=5,%
        xunit=1,%
        yunit=5%
        ](-3,-2)(4,4)
    \newcommand\f[1]{%
        -5. - 4.48782*#1 + 2.34728*(#1)^2 + 0.891565*(#1)^3 + 0.51223*(#1)^4 + 0.492146*(#1)^5 - 0.0823567*(#1)^6 - 0.0593091*(#1)^7
        }% f(x)
    \psplot{-2.5}{2.1}{%
        \f{x}
        }
    \psdots(-2.5,-5)(2.1,16.5)
    \psline[linewidth=2.4pt](-2.5,0)(2.1,0) % D_f
    \uput{.1cm}[-90](0.7,0){$\mathcal{D}_f$} % D_f
    \psline[linewidth=2.4pt](0,-6.5)(0,16.5) % V_f
    \uput{.1cm}[0](0,12){$\mathcal{V}_f$} % V_f
    \psline(-2.1,-3)(-2.1,0)
    \uput{.1cm}[-90](-2.1,-3){Zéro}
    \psline(-0.85,-3)(-0.85,0)
    \uput{.1cm}[-90](-0.85,-3){Zéro}
    \psline(1.45,-3)(1.45,0)
    \uput{.1cm}[-90](1.45,-3){Zéro}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](-2.5,-5)(-2.5,0)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](-2,0)(-2,1)(0,1)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](0,-6.5)(0.5,-6.5)
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](2.1,0)(2.1,16.5)(0,16.5)
\end{pspicture*}
%%%%%%% Fig 1Fp112 - 2023-24 - END %%%%%%%
\\[\baselineskip]
%%%%%%% Fig 1Fp113 - 2023-24 - BEGIN %%%%%%%
\psset{%
    xunit=1cm,%
    yunit=.2cm,%
    algebraic=true,%
    dotstyle=*,%
    dotsize=5pt 0,%
    linewidth=.8pt,% default: 0.8pt
    arrowsize=3pt 2,%
    arrowinset=0.25%
    }
\def\xmin{-3.9}
\def\xmax{4.4}
\def\ymin{-8}
\def\ymax{16}
\begin{pspicture*}(\xmin,\ymin)(\xmax,\ymax)
    \small
    \psaxes[%
        linewidth=.8pt,%
        labelFontSize=\normalsize,%
        xAxis=true,%
        yAxis=true,%
        showorigin=false,%
        Dx=1,%
        Dy=5,%
        ticksize=-3pt,%
        xsubticks=2,%
        ysubticks=5%
        ]{->}(0,0)(\xmin,\ymin)(\xmax,\ymax)
    \uput{.2cm}[120](\xmax,0){$x$}
    \uput{.2cm}[-30](0,\ymax){$y$}
    \psgrid[%
        gridcolor=black,% default: grey
        griddots=5,%
        gridlabels=0pt,%
        subgriddiv=0,%
        subgriddots=5,%
        xunit=1,%
        yunit=5%
        ](-4,-2)(4,4)
    \psdots(-3,13)(-2,3)(-1.58,0)(-1,-3)(0,-5)(1,-3)(1.58,0)(2,3)(3,13)
    \uput[180](-2,3){$(-2;3)$}
    \uput[45](-1.58,0){$Z_1$}
    \uput[-45](0,-5){$H(0;-5)$}
    \uput[135](1.58,0){$Z_2$}
    \uput[0](3,13){$(3;13)$}
\end{pspicture*}
%%%%%%% Fig 1Fp113 - 2023-24 - END %%%%%%%
\end{document}



The labels are set in mathmode and in your first pspictures you have
    labelFontSize=\normalsize,%
    labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,%

where only the second one is valid!  In your second pspicture you have
    labelFontSize=\normalsize,%

which leads to the labels in \normalsize. Change it to \scriptstyle and it will be of the same size as in the first pspicture. The setting \small  is only valid for text set by \rput  and others.


Gosh, I really must be tired... I looked through my code several times, and I didn't see that!!! Well, thanks for having checked it, and thanks a lot for your answer. Next time I will wait some days before asking questions...
